# Adding a column of values to a table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a dataset of players from a game with their attributes, team, league, and country that they're from. I want to make a table that has each distinct team and shows their overall rating, their n best players, and the average of those players.

I can get the values by themselves using this:

```
    select distinct Team, nth_value(Current, 2) #get nth largest value 
          from column over (partition by Team) as player2 #best nth player by team
          from master
          order by Current DESC; #ordered by best player
```

And this:

```
    select Team, round(avg(Current),2) as 'Average' #average player on team
          from master
          group by Team;
```

I made a table for the teams and their averages, but I can't find a way to add the column of nth best player to it. The closest that I've found is adding a row of information to the table.

Essentially, the table should look something like:

```
Team | Average_Rating | Best_Player | Second_Best | ... | Nth_Best | Avg_20
Name | 93.67          | 142         | 120         | ... | 72       | 96.25
```

Comment: the second value in `nth_value(Current, 2)` can change between requests as i assume that `team` column not having a primary or unique key meaning on equal values within the team column you can't predict which record is processed there..  We need the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE master`

Comment: ... also `select Team, round(avg(Current),2)` is not a valid query its meaningless to mix a non aggregate column with a aggregated function `avg()` ... i advice you to see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results as these SQL codes contains unlogical errors

Comment: I don't know if it's applicable in your situation, but if you can do some post-processing after your query, you could try something like `SELECT Team, GROUP_CONCAT(Current ORDER BY Current DESC) AS scores FROM master GROUP BY Team`, and then split the scores (with `explode()` in PHP, for example)

Comment: @Pepper your suggestion would also have trouble with equal values within the team column you can't predict which records values is on the ntn position within the comma separated values..

Comment: @RaymondNijland sample from master:

Comment: player_id,Name,Team,League,Nationality,Age,Current,Min_Potential,Max_Potential,Avg_Potential,Positions
1,"Messi, Lionel",Barcelona,"Spanish First Division",Argentina,31,195,199,199,199,"AM (RC), ST (C)"
2,"Ronaldo, Cristiano",Juventus,"Italian Serie A",Portugal,33,195,196,196,196,"AM (RL), ST (C)"
3,"Neuer, Manuel","Bayern Munich","German Bundesliga",Germany,32,186,193,193,193,GK
4,Rodrygo,Santos,"Brazilian National First Division",Brazil,17,130,160,190,178,"AM (L), ST (C)"
5,"Pellegri, Pietro","AS Monaco","Ligue 1 Conforama",Italy,17,114,160,190,178,"ST (C)"

Comment: Also, @RaymondNijland I used select Team, round(avg(Current),2) to make sure the values were correct corresponding to each team.